# BUG? topic subscription shutdown() fails to shutdown

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The scenerio is we are trying to do custom kinect calibration and we need both
raw IR and RGB image. The kinect/asus hardware do not support stream ir and
rgb at the same time, so we need to switch back and forth between two topics, or we will get a "can't stream ir and rgb at the same time, stream rgb only now" warning from ros. The problem is I tried sub.shutdown() the rgb topic subscription but still can't add IR topic subscription and get the same warning. I also tried use ros::topic::waitForMessage<sensor_msgs::Image>("/camera/rgb/image_mono", *nodeHandle); which is suppose to subscribe->get a frame of data ->unsubscribe. But I still get the same warning. It seems neither shutdown() nor waitForMessage is able to turn off the subscription to a topic. Is this a bug or I am doing something wrong here? Insights welcomed. Thank you!

Best,
Ranqi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40662/bug?-topic-subscription-shutdown()-fails-to-shutdown./) by [ranqi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2941/ranqi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the documentation of [Subscriber.shutdown()](http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1Subscriber.html#a4d34ead7d36f6d5ba4fac7e9465e4e6b) it states that it unsubscribes the callback it does not state that it unsubscribes the topic.  You might need to destroy the Subscriber instance.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0